# How to create .dsym file in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this should be a simple problem to solve, but I'm stumped.

Using Xcode 6.4, how can I create the .dsym file (this is for submission for Veracode  scanning, if that matters).

All the instructions I can find are for Xcode <=5, and don't fully translate to Xcode 6.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After archiving your app, in your derived data

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Go to your application

```
AppName-xxxxxxxxx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
```

your .dsym file will be in this folder.

Comment: 1). thanks! I can't believe I didn't figure this out earlier.
2). You may want to change the /WigigDeals/ to a generic, since that is an app name :)

Answer (score 0):

Finding the dSYM of a particular build through the Terminal can be quite cumbersome. Instead, use Xcode to do that. In the `Window` menu, choose `Organiser`. A list of your apps and archives appears. Select the one you are interested in. Right-click on it, and choose `Show in Finder`. You will end up in a directory with files called `<AppName>-<ArchiveDate>.xcarchive`, with the archive you selected in Xcode already selected in the Finder. Right-click again on it, and choose `Show Package Contents`. And you'll find here a `dSYMs` folder.